# How to Nest Date Functions in SOQL Advanced Filter in Einstein Analytics Data Flow

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-einstein

How do I nest date functions in SOQL Advanced Filters -> sfdcDigest node -> Data Flows -> Einstein Analytics to filter which records to pull?

I tried using `CALENDAR_YEAR(ClosedDateTime)=THIS_YEAR`, but received an error that ClosedDateTime has to be integer?. Reading through SF KB, I realized that CALENDAR_YEAR accepts Date, but not DateTime format. To convert, I can use DAY_ONLY(ClosedDateTime). Now, how do I put all this together? Advanced filter excepts WHERE portion of SOQL query.

I tried `CALENDAR_YEAR(DAY_ONLY(ClosedDateTime))=THIS_YEAR` but got an error about nested function.

I expect filter to pull only opportunities closed in current year.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you search internets a little longer...

```
CompletedDateTime = THIS_YEAR
```

This worked for the filter, but still not sure if it possible to nest functions :)